# Derivatives of $\csc(x)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

The derivative of $\csc x$ is $(-\csc x)(\cot x) =(\frac{-1}{\sin x} ) ( \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} ) $

When I take the derivative of $ x \csc(2x-1) $, I get $\frac{x}{\sin(2x-1)}= \frac{\sin(2x-1) - 2x\cos(2x-1)}{\sin^2(2x-1)} $

How does my answer above link to the formula that I written at the top?

In the numerator , there is $\sin$ when the formula states it will only have $\cos$

Sorry I'm trying to simplify and understand $\csc$

Comment: The one question that needs serious editing...I can't edit >_<

Comment: @KKZiomek What do you mean? With 1000+ rep you should easily be able to edit any post (or at least propose an edit... I forget the rep levels)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen It is 2000+ reputation in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if $F'(x) = f(x)$, then $\frac{d}{dx} F(ax+b) = af(ax+b)$, by the chain rule. So $\frac{d}{dx}\csc(2x-1) = -2\csc(2x-1)\cot(2x-1)$. Therefore, using the product rule,
$$\frac{d}{dx} x\csc(2x-1) = \csc(2x-1)\left(\frac{d}{dx} x\right)+x\left(\frac{d}{dx} \csc(2x-1) \right)$$
$$ = \csc(2x-1)-2x\csc(2x-1)\cot(2x-1)$$
$$= \frac{1-2x\cot(2x-1)}{\sin(2x-1)} = \frac{\sin(2x-1)-2x\cos(2x-1)}{\sin^2(2x-1)}$$
The last equality comes from multiplying the top and bottom by $\sin(2x-1)$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}\dfrac d{dx}(\csc x)&=\dfrac d{dx}\left(\dfrac1{\sin x}\right)\\&=\dfrac d{dx}(\sin x)^{-1}\\&=-(\sin x)^{-2}\dfrac d{dx}(\sin x)\\&=-\dfrac{\cos x}{\sin^2 x}\\&=-\dfrac 1{\sin x}\cdot\dfrac{\cos x}{\sin x}\\&=-\csc x\cot x\end{align}$$

Now let's use this result, to find the derivative of your function

$$\begin{align}\dfrac d{dx}(x\csc(2x-1))&=x\dfrac d{dx}(\csc(2x-1))+\csc(2x-1)\dfrac d{dx}(x)\\&=-x\csc(2x-1)\cot(2x-1)\dfrac d{dx}(2x-1)+\csc(2x-1)\\&=-2x\csc(2x-1)\cot(2x-1)+\csc(2x-1)\\&=(1-2x\cot(2x-1))\csc(2x-1)\end{align}$$

If you change the ratios to $\sin(2x-1)$ and $\cos(2x-1)$ and simplify, or multiply top and bottom by $\sin(2x-1)$, then it will match up with the result that you have.

See if this makes things a little clear

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, since your title is "Derivativ**e̲s̲** of $\csc x$", we can note that $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\csc(x)=i^n \csc (x) \sum _{j=0}^n \sum _{k=0}^j (-1)^k k! 2^{j-k} \binom{n}{j} \left\{ {j \atop k}\right\} (1-i \cot (x))^k$$
From here, the solution is "*obvious*" ;)